# Xamarin Forms - ListView HeaderTemplate constructor called twice

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I do the following.

- Construct a ContentPage
- Create a new AbsoluteLayout
- Add a new ListView as a child of the AbsoluteLayout.
  The HeaderTemplate of the ListView is of Type MyHeader
- Set the Content of the ContentPage to be the AbsoluteLayout

What I noticed and didn't expect is that the contructor of MyHeader is called at the time I create the ListView but ALSO when I set the Content of the ContentPage.

A bit of code to illustrate:

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        //layout
        var abs = new AbsoluteLayout();

        //elements
        var myList = new ListView
        {
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCell)),
            HeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyHeader)) //will call constructor of MyHeader
        };

        //bindings
        myList.SetBinding<IMyContentPageViewModel>(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, x => x.GetMyCellsCommand.Execution.Result);
        myList.SetBinding<IMyContentPageViewModel>(ListView.HeaderProperty, x => x.MyHeaderViewModel);

        //page
        abs.Children.Add(myList, new Rectangle( 0.0, 0.0, 300, 300 ));

        //set content
        Content = abs; //will call constructor of MyHeader as well
    }
}
```

I don't see anything similar with the ItemTemplate, which is called once.
Why such a behavior for the HeaderTemplate?
Tks.